# What does a number in a module name mean in Intellij IDEA project view?

Tags: intellij-idea

I believe that is "static web" module.

[image: Intellij IDEA 14 project view]

Please notice "6" number on the screenshot. I don't know when it appeared and what it means.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a bookmark. To show and edit bookmarks use the following menu: `Navigate > Bookmarks > Show bookmarks`

Comment: Press **Ctrl+F11** to add number icon for bookmarking.